# How can I publish my website with VisualStudio and track the changes?

Tags: asp.net, publishing

Does anybody have an idea how to use he "publish website" command on VS 2008 and be able to track changes so as to only sent to the hosting server the modified files?

When the command is called, the destination folder files are wiped and replaced with the result of the new build (assembly file are created as well as some marker files).As my website is getting bigger and bigger I have to transfer to the server all the assemblies in my bin directory and keep in mind which other files I may have modified.

Is there a better way of doing this?

ps: I use FileZila to transfer my files to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Publish to a local directory, then use a diff tool (such as [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/)) to find and copy the modified files to the server.

Comment: A diff tools between the server and the files in the local directory? the problem is that most of the files transfered to the server are binaries (.dll or .compiled for asp.net) so differences between assemblies are not done with the actual content of the file but rather the date and size.

Answer (score 1):

You can publish locally and use any mechanism of your choice to transfer the files.

Comment: That's what i am already doing, but locally, all the files seem different since they are binaries...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried **Website->Copy Website** menu item? It seems to know which files are changed.

Comment: It does know which files have been modified , but such files are different from the one that i put on the server (assembly files vs sinple code files such as vb or c#)

Comment: @seylom: I suggest you first deploy locally (keeping only the files you want) and then do the copy to your remote site.

Comment: i would like to avoid transferring code to the server (like .vb or.cs files). or maybe i am not using the tool right.

Comment: @muragtu: that's what i am doing.Maybe my question was not clear... how do you know what needs to be copied and what doesn't when you can track changes from the deployed build?